# gazebo on ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys :)

1. can i install GAZEBO on **UBUNTU 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot)** and ros fuerte form gazebosim.org?
2. **which version?**
3. do you have any link?

tnx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1628/gazebo-on-ubuntu-11.10-(oneiric)?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently you can install from source: http://gazebosim.org/downloads.html

We do not provide binaries for 11.10, so you'll have to install from source. Just grab the latest tarball.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1